# Does the same answer make two different questions duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently posted a question on StackOverflow. However, it was flagged as duplicate. The reason mentioned in the comments was that another, **different** question, has the same answer. Is that right? Does the same answer make two different questions duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes.

Your question can be answered by another answer already on stack overflow.

This means that someone can just copy-paste that other answer, and voila, you get an answer. While it might not be an **exact** duplicate, it won't benefit a future reader more than the other question would.

Comment: It will since the future reader will not know to look for the other question.

Comment: @Sipo except for the massive "this has been answered here" banner. But I get your point.